# Insert date into another column's cell using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a hyperlink in Excel. What I want it to essentially do is to send an email (which I have done using a formula as it uses various VLOOKUPs) and also add's today's date into another cell (indicating the date the email was sent).

Each row in column D contains this hyperlink and depending on information on each row a different hyperlink is created. Once the hyperlink is pressed, I want the equivalent's row AD to state today's date.

i.e. if I click the hyperlink in cell D4, AD4 will have an output of today's date (and a create new email window appears).

I am quite new to macro building but what I guess needs to be done is a listener checks to see if a hyperlink is clicked in the column D
Once it is clicked, it takes the cell I've clicked into and add the number of columns into it to turn it from D to AD, then output today's date.

Comment: Why a hyperlink? The hyperlink doesn't actually act like a hyperlink but rather acts like a button? Why not hitch your VBA code to the Worksheet DoubleClick event instead? Or stick a button in there? Or use Worksheet_SelectionChange(). Hyperlink seems like an odd event to attach to.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by using HYPERLINK you are using the mailto command to create an email? Either way... you can use the following:

Open VBA and paste the below code in the Sheet Object (e.g. Sheet1(Sheet1)) part of the VBA. Every time in Sheet1 if you click on a cell in column 4 it will put the date in the appropriate row of AD (change as appropriate).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If ActiveCell.Column = 4 Then
    Range("AD" & Target.Row).Value = Date
Else
End If
End Sub
```

This is very basic, you could add a check to see that the cell clicked contained a HYPERLINK, or perhaps prompt with a message box confirming the email send and date add.